# Chaining functions using Repository Pattern with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, dependency-injection, repository-pattern, awilix

I have a BaseRepository with the main methods that mongoose provides like this:

```
class BaseRepository {
  constructor(model) {
    this.model = model;
  }

  async get(id) {
    return this.model.findById(id);
  }

  async find(filter) {
    return this.model.find(filter);
  }
  
  async sort(filter) {
    return this.model.sort(filter)
  }

  ....
}
```

And so I'm using a dependency injection pattern with awilix so I can use them like this on my service layer, for example my userRepository:

```
this.userRepository.find({})
```

And everything works fine, the problem lies when I try to chain my repository methods like this:

```
this.userRepository.find({}).sort({createdAt: -1})
```

I get the following error:

```
this.userRepository.find(...).sort is not a function
```

I'll gladly accept a few suggestions on how to make this work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `async` modifier. When a method/function is marked as `async`, it will always return a `Promise`. In your case, you want to return the object returned by mongoose's `find`, which is a querying API object.

Comment: Don't know how I overlooked that haha. Exactly what I was looking. Thanks sir!